# Set syntax highlighting for [biopython] to lang-py

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Currently, [biopython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biopython) does not have a syntax highlighting language set. Since this is a Python package, I'd like to request that it be set to `lang-py`, as there are [a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biopython+-python) of [biopython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biopython) questions that are not simultaneously tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or one of its variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to just retag them to include a Python tag. This will apply syntax highlighting, and more importantly, it will get more attention to those questions. Currently, there are 65 questions tagged [biopython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biopython) that **do not** also have either [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), or [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). 40% of those questions are unanswered. Compare that to a 23% unanswered rate for all questions tagged [biopython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biopython). The ones with another Python tag have a much better chance of getting answered.